# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable "str(n1[::-1])"

Tags: python

I keep getting a error.

line 8, in main
    n3 = str(n1) + str(n) + str(n1[::-1]) + str(n2)

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

```
def main():
    n = eval(input("enter the number"))

    n1 = 1
    n2 = 21 

    for i in range(n-2):

        n3 = str(n1) + str(i+3) + str(n1[::-1]) + str(n2)
        print("\n",n3)

        n1 = n2
        n2 = n3
main()
```

I am trying to store string(n1) + string(i+3) + string(reversed list of numbers) + string(n2) into a variable n3.

I claimed the values as Strings and I don't understand why error says 'integer' object...

Comment: `n1[::-1]`  of an `int` ?

Answer (score 2):

It should be `str(n1)[::-1]` if you wish to convert `n1` to `str` and then use slicing. Brackets matters.

Comment: Thank you so much!